# WPF: Element Justification

Tags: wpf, xaml, stackpanel, dockpanel

Is there a way to justify three or more elements in WPF along the window size,
in such a way that it would look like this:

```
[button]        [button]        [button]        [button]
________________________________________________________
```

I tried searching for ways using dockpanel/stackpanel, but they only seem to use two elements (for attaching one to the left, and one to the right, for example.)

Comment: use Grid or UniformGrid http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample using `UniformGrid`

```
    <UniformGrid Columns="4">
        <Button Content="1" />
        <Button Content="2" />
        <Button Content="3" />
        <Button Content="4" />
    </UniformGrid>
```

if you do not want to fix the columns to 4 then fix the rows to 1 and all the buttons will be uniformly spaced

```
    <UniformGrid Rows="1">
        <Button Content="1" />
        <Button Content="2" />
        <Button Content="3" />
        <Button Content="4" />
        <Button Content="5" />
        <Button Content="6" />
    </UniformGrid>
```